# How do I get the number of character repetitions in a few names in the following program?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I want to write a program that, with the help of pointers, takes the names of a number of people from the input and receives one character from the input for each row of the array and prints the number of repetitions of that character in the array line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
   int n, i, j;
   char str[30][30];
   printf ("how many names?:");
   scanf ("%d", &n);
   int m = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      char ch, *s;
      scanf ("%s", str[i]);
      gets (str[i]);
      s = str[i];
      ch = getche ();
      while (*s)    if (*s++ == ch)       m++;
      printf ("%d\n", m);
    }
   return 0;
}
```

This program is incomplete and wrong. I want to know how we can take a letter from each of the names separately from the input and get the number of repetitions after giving the name entries to the program.

**input:** 2** leonardo ** peter ** o ** p ///// 
**output:** 
how many names?  
2 
please enter 1th name:  
leonardo  
please enter 2th name:  
peter  
Number of repetitions Which letter of the name 1 do you want?  
o  
2  
Number ofrepetitions Which letter of the name 2 do you want?  
p  
1

Comment: Is this the right way for me to write a program at all? What better way do you suggest?

Comment: Which OS is this? Which compiler? Why you do a scanf and gets both?

Comment: @kiner_shah  That part is incorrect, I just let it show what I mean.

Comment: Please provide sample input and its expected output.

Comment: @kiner_shah     windows 10-dev c++

Comment: @kiner_shah input:   2  **   leonardo **    peter **   o  **    p   /////                                     output:  how many times? ** 2  ** please enter 1th name: **leonardo**please enter 2th name**Number of repetitions Which letter of the name 1 do you want?**o**2**Number of repetitions Which letter of the name 2 do you want?**p**1

Comment: Please don't post in comments, edit the post and include in the post itself. Also, make sure to properly format the post so that it's readable.

Comment: This looks like a homework question and you seem to be asking for a solution. You have a code but that's nowhere near the desired solution - in fact it doesn't even work. I would recommend that you post the code which shows your honest attempt at solving your problem and in there if you are facing issues, it will be solved here.

Comment: @kiner_shah   That code does not matter, I just left it for others to understand, because it is difficult to say the question I have.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a struct say containing the name and the count of all characters.

```
struct name_st
{
    char name[30];
    int count[26];
};
```

Create an array of the `struct` objects like: `struct name_st s[30];`

Read each `name` in the for loop like `scanf("%s", s[i].name);`

- For each name, after reading you can parse the `name` character by character and update the `count` for each character like `s[i].count[s[i].name[j] - 'a']++;`

Then in another for loop, read the character you want to display the count for in the `i`th name, and simply output the `count` for that particular character like `printf("%d", s[i].count[c - 'a']);`